# Always a loop, bad practice?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like know if i need to create a forEach loop when i would like add an event on my element ?

My code contain a lot of loop like this :

```
  const $itemUpload = document.querySelectorAll('.js-file-upload'); // ~ 10 elements in my page

  // Image preview before upload
  [...$itemUpload].forEach((item) => {

    const $parent = item.closest('.js-upload-container');

    item.addEventListener('change', function() {

      const options = [
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.js-file-image'),
        this.files[0],
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.js-file-wording'),
      ];
      const upload = new Upload(...options);
      const $buttonClear = this.parentNode.querySelector('.js-remove-file');

      upload.previewFile();

      $parent.classList.add(activeClass);

    });

  });
```

And the same kind of processing for the remove button (forEach loot on .js-remove-file.

I wonder if this is the right way. When my page load, it executes several loops for an event that may not be created (click to delete an item in cart, present on all pages).

Do you have a suggestion ?

Thank you community !

Comment: If all the items of a collection have to get the same event, add One event to the parent or another higherlvl container instead of adding the same event to each item. You can refer to the actualy changed item with event.target inside the handler.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a noticeable performance problem when loading your site? If not, why worry?

Comment: Yop :) Thank for your response. No noticeable performance problem, but i think this approch (alway a loop) is not good ^^

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with a loop when you have 10 elements that require the same treatment. Maybe the only valid question would be "can I let those event bubble up to a common ancestor and handle them there?"

Comment: For example, add a loop on a parent container (<li> contain my 2 buttons) and event in this loop ?

Comment: you should learn about event delegation instead of attaching an event listener to every element of the array

Comment: The proper ES6y syntax would be `for (const item of $itemUpload) { … }`